# Nested tikzpicture using \node

Tags: matlab2tikz, tikz-node

I want to make comments onto a matlab2tikz figure. One way is to nest the matlab generated code using a \node inside a tikzpicture.

However, when I do so, the axis labels and axis tick labels get "messed up". To show you, my MWE consists of two figures: One normal one and one nested figure with messed up ticks+labels.

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85,shellesc}
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}   
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=figures_tex/]
\pgfplotsset{plot coordinates/math parser=false}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \tikzsetnextfilename{test_fig}
    \input{test_fig.tex}
    \caption{figure without comments}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \tikzsetnextfilename{test_fig_comments}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        %%The matlab2tikz plot is drawn as a node
        \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (myplot) at (0,0) {
        \input{test_fig.tex}
        };
        \begin{scope}[x={(myplot.south east)}, y={(myplot.north west)}]
            %%Comment
            \draw[<-,thick,red] (0.6,.53)--(.7,.4) 
            node[right,draw=red,rounded corners,
            text width=1cm,align=center,text=black] 
            {$f(x)$};
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{figure with comments}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The test_fig.tex file, which was created using matlab2tikz:

```
% This file was created by matlab2tikz.
%
%The latest updates can be retrieved from
%  http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz-matlab2tikz
%where you can also make suggestions and rate matlab2tikz.
%
\definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0.00000,0.44700,0.74100}%
%
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=6.656cm,
height=5cm,
at={(0cm,0cm)},
scale only axis,
xmin=1,
xmax=5,
xlabel={$x$ [-]},
xmajorgrids,
ymin=1,
ymax=5,
ylabel={$f(x)$ [-]},
ymajorgrids,
axis background/.style={fill=white},
axis x line*=bottom,
axis y line*=left,
legend style={legend cell align=left,align=left,draw=white!15!black},
legend style={font=\tiny}, ticklabel style={font=\footnotesize}, xlabel style={font=\small}, ylabel style={font=\small}
]
\addplot [color=mycolor1,solid,line width=1.2pt]
   table[row sep=crcr]{%
1   1\\
2   2\\
3   3\\
4   4\\
5   5\\
};
\addlegendentry{data1};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

For me the result looks like:
[image: Normal and nested figure]

You can see that the tick labels overlap with the axes. Therefore my question: How to retain its format when nesting the matlab2tikz figure inside a \node?

Thank you in advance! Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Your question is the wrong question. Never nest `tikzpicture`s. In simple cases, it may work, but it is expected to break and should (almost) always be avoided. `tikzmark` provides `\subnode` for these kinds of cases.

Comment: Well, unfortunately I am not familiar with tikz/pgfplots very much. I only use the matlab2tikz tool tbh. That might be why I try to solve the "wrong problem". Anyways, thanks for the hint...I've checked tixmark. It seems I have to alter the matlab2tikz code, but I would like to avoid this in order to easily update the matlab figure.

Comment: You could include it as an image. You should also try not externalising it.

Comment: I'm not sure how well `tikzmark` would work with `pgfplots` anyway. Including it as an external image is probably the way to go here.

Comment: Jap, actually that is what I did in the end: included it as an external image. It is a little workaround since I have to compile the new image first when the figure is updated....but it is reasonable effort. Thanks and I'll close this one.

Comment: You can also execute tex_fig.tex inside a savebox (before the tikzpicture) then use \usebox inside the node.